# Что такое сокращение и условное обозначение

Tags: сокращения

В диссертациях и др. документах раздел сокращений может называться:

- перечень сокращений
- перечень условных обозначений
- перечень сокращений и условных обозначений

Я так понимаю, что в зависимости от того, что в раздел входит (только сокращения, только условные обозначения или то и другое), он и будет менять название.

Но что такое сокращение, а что такое условное обозначение? Где граница? Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Условные обозначения чаще всего являются аббревиатурами или специальными символами, характерными только для этой области. Например, **А** в физике это условное обозначение **работы**, а в биологии уже **"аденин"**. МГУ - пример аббревиатуры-обозначения. Они расшифровываются один раз в начале разговора о предмете:

*"Электролитическая диссоциация (в дальнейшем - ЭД)
ЭД - и пошло определение, дальше необходимые условия и прочее."*

С сокращениями всё ещё проще. *Электр.дисс.* - вот Вам и сокращение. Или так: *кол-во*. Они чаще всего неудобней, но иногда необходимы, например, если есть ещё одно обозначение ЭД, означающее что-либо друге ("эллипс Диккенса", "эму дикий", ...)

Answer (score -1):

Электролитическая диссоциация = электр. дисс. или ЭД — сокращения.

А = работа — обозначение.